# How to write two-way binding in dart angular

Tags: angular, dart

I need a component to choose user role with two-way binding

> role-chooser-comp.html

```
<div class="roleChooser">
  <role-item #owner (select)="role(owner.role)" [role]="'owner'" [title]="'Owner'"></role-item>
  <role-item #writer (select)="role(writer.role)" [role]="'writer'" [title]="'Writer'"></role-item>
  <role-item #viewer (select)="role(viewer.role)" [role]="'viewer'" [title]="'Reader'"></role-item>
</div>
```

its class is the following:

> role-chooser-comp.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'role-chooser-comp',
    templateUrl: 'role_chooser_comp.html',
    styleUrls: const ['role_chooser_comp.css'],
    directives: const [RoleItem])
class RoleChooser implements OnInit {
  final PlaceService _placeService;
  final Router _router;
  final Environment _environment;

  @ViewChild('owner') RoleItem owner;
  @ViewChild('writer') RoleItem writer;
  @ViewChild('viewer') RoleItem viewer;
  List<RoleItem> choices;
  String lastSelected;

  RoleChooser(this._placeService, this._router, this._environment) {

  }

  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
    choices = [owner, writer, viewer];
    if (lastSelected != null)
      role(lastSelected);
  }

  String get selected => lastSelected;

  @Input()
  set selected(String role) {
    //on init, the choices are still not set
    if (choices == null)
      lastSelected = role;
    else
      this.role(role);
  }

  void role(String role) {
    if (choices == null) {
      window.alert("No roles are set");
      return;
    }

    for (RoleItem item in choices) {
      if (item.role == role) {
        item.selected = true;
        lastSelected = role;
      } else {
        item.selected = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I need is to be able to update the value of my model automatically in a use like :

> usecase

```
<role-chooser-comp [(selected)]="userRole.roleName"></role-chooser-comp>
```

or

```
<role-chooser-comp [(ngModel)]="userRole.roleName"></role-chooser-comp>
```

I found an article about angular.js that show how to use [(ngModel)] with any element (implementing two methods so angular knows how to get the value from the component and backward) : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms (section **Implementing custom form controls (using ngModel)**)

I'd like to do the same in dart, but I don't know how...

The role item is very simple for now, I just paste it for reference :

> role-item.html

```
<div class="role" [class.selected]="selected" (click)="clicked()">
      <btn #icon
          [sources]="images"></btn>
    </div>
```

> role-item.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';

import 'package:share_place/environment.dart';
import 'package:share_place/place_service.dart';

import 'package:share_place/common/ui/button_comp.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'role-item',
    templateUrl: 'role_item.html',
    styleUrls: const ['role_item.css'],
    directives: const [ButtonComp])
class RoleItem {
  final PlaceService _placeService;
  final Router _router;
  final Environment _environment;
  @Output() final EventEmitter<String> pressAction = new EventEmitter<String>();
  @Output() final EventEmitter<String> select = new EventEmitter<String>();

  get role => itemRole;

  @Input() set role(String role) {
    itemRole = role;
    images = [
      '../images/roles/$role.png',
      '../images/roles/$role-h.png',
      '../images/roles/$role-c.png'
    ];
  }

  @Input() String title;
  @Input() String desc;

  @ViewChild('icon')
  ButtonComp icon;

  String itemRole;

  List<String> images;
  bool isSelected = false;

  bool toggle = false;

  RoleItem(this._placeService, this._router, this._environment);

  void clicked() {
    bool newlySelected;
    if (!isSelected)
      newlySelected = true;

    if (toggle)
      selected = !selected;
    else
      selected = true;

    pressAction.emit(role);
    if (newlySelected)
      select.emit(role);
  }

  bool get selected => isSelected;

  void set selected(bool isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    icon.select(isSelected);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add

```
@Output() EventEmitter<String> selectedChange = new EventEmitter<String>();
```

to your `RoleChooser` component.

To notify about changes call

```
selectedChange.add('foo');
```

then `userRole.roleName` from

```
<role-chooser-comp [(selected)]="userRole.roleName"></role-chooser-comp>
```

will be updated.

Comment: Whooow! that's too smart for me! How does it work? Hwo does it know that I want to call the setter of userRole (by just emitting an event that has nothing to do with my [(selected)] value???

Comment: `[selected]="userRole.roleName"` assigns `userRole.roleName` to `selected`, (selectedChange)="userRole.roleName = $event"` assigns changes in the other direction. The shorthand for both together is `[(selected)]="userRole.roleName"`. Angular evaluates these bindings every time when it runs change detection.

Comment: So the key is in the naming? the @output name must be selectedChange for it to work?

Comment: In other workds, if I named my @Output onSelect it wouldn't work??

Comment: No, then only the event binding `(onSelect)="..."` could be used but not the shorthand for value + event-binding. For this the output has to have the same name as the input with an additional `Change` suffix.

Comment: thanks a lot for these answers. Event though I don't find this specification safe, I'd have prefered a @Output("select") form that explicitely binds itself to the field : the actual way is very poor in time resistence, for example if we refactor the "selected" attribute and rename it to "currentSelection" for example, the code might break silently and introduce hard to find bugs...

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_analyzer_plugin should help with that. Currently work-in-progress but if you have a matching Dart version you can use it and it is of great help already.